# Вывод данных в ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

Сейчас у меня есть коллекция данных, которую я вывожу в нужном мне виде в ItemsControl.
У меня выводится по 10 записей на страницу и я могу листать эти страницы и просматривать данные.

**View:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Books, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                // Данные
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<Button Command="{Binding PreviousPageCommand}"
        Text="Предыдущая страница"/>

<Button Command="{Binding NextPageCommand}"
        Text="Следующая страница"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ObservableCollection<Models.Books> OriginalBooks { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Models.Books> Books { get; set; }

private int CurrentPage { get; set; }


private void OnRefresh()
{
    var books = _fileService.OnReadFile();

    OriginalBooks.Clear();
    foreach (var book in books)
    {
        OriginalBooks.Add(book);
    }

    UpdateVisibleBooks();
}

private void OnPreviousPage()
{
    if (CurrentPage <= 1) return;
    CurrentPage--;
    UpdateVisibleBooks();
}

private void OnNextPage()
{
    if (OriginalBooks.Count - 1 > 10 * CurrentPage - 1)
    {
        CurrentPage++;
        UpdateVisibleBooks();
    }
}

private void UpdateVisibleBooks()
{
    Books.Clear();
    for (var i = (CurrentPage - 1) * 10; i < CurrentPage * 10; i++)
    {
        if (i < OriginalBooks.Count)
        {
            var book = OriginalBooks[i];
            Books.Add(book);
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: как мне сделать так, что бы при изменении размера окна ItemsControl выводил именно то кол-во записей из коллекции, которое может вместиться в текущий размер окна приложения? К примеру я уменьшил размер окна и теперь на экране вмещается только 5 записей, тогда при перелистывании на след страницу должны появляться записи не с 10-й по 20-ю (Как у меня сейчас), а с 5-й по 10-ю. Возможно ли вообще сделать такое в WPF?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, вам нужно пересчитывать размер страницы и текущую страницу. дело только за тем, чтобы понять сколько в текущий размер влазит элементов.

Comment: Лучше всего, я думаю, написать свою панель для этого, вам ведь придется как-то из VM реагировать на изменение вместимости страницы

Comment: Зачем это делать? Чтобы не тянуть все записи в грид, можно использовать виртуализацию, не обязательно делать пейджинг.

Comment: @tym32167 почитал про виртуализацию, вроде как она может мне помочь. Только вот лаб работа требует использования пагинации. Можно ли реализовать пагинацию с виртуализацией?

Comment: нет, если вам пейджинг надо обязательно, то виртуализация вам не поможет.